# Get or Set CSS Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Does jQuery have a way to get and set the value of CSS variables? ([MDN - Using CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables))

I have tried using the normal css function `$(".element").css("--varname", 1)`, but it doesn't work.

I can use normal DOM functions, but I would prefer not to mix that and jQuery:

```
element.style.getPropertyValue("--varname");
element.style.setProperty("--varname", value);
```

I am using this variable in a `transform`, so getting the result of using the variable gives a `matrix3d()` string. I need to get the value for some calculations in JS

Comment: You are missing {}. $('.classname').css({'display': 'block'});

Comment: @Nitin I think he meant literal css variables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: CSS variables aren't associated with specific elements, they're used in the `<style>` section of the document.

Comment: @Barmar Not true, CSS variables are set on specific elements and then inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.cssHooks`, `$.support`

```js
(function($) {

  // First, check to see if cssHooks are supported
  if (!$.cssHooks) {
    // If not, output an error message
    throw (new Error("jQuery 1.4.3 or above is required"
                     + " for this plugin to work"));
  }

  // Wrap in a document ready call, because jQuery writes
  // cssHooks at this time and will blow away your functions
  // if they exist.
  $(function() {

    $.cssHooks["mainBgColor"] = {
      get: function(elem, computed, extra) {
        // Handle getting the CSS property
        return elem.style.getPropertyValue($.support["mainBgColor"]) 
               || window.getComputedStyle(elem)
                 .getPropertyValue($.support["mainBgColor"])
      },
      set: function(elem, value) {
        // Handle setting the CSS value
        elem.style.setProperty($.support["mainBgColor"], value);
        return elem
      }
    };
    $.support["mainBgColor"] = "--main-bg-color";
    console.log($("h1").css("mainBgColor")); // `"brown"`
    $("h1").css("mainBgColor", "green");
    console.log($("h1").css("mainBgColor")); // `"green"`
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
h1 {
  --main-bg-color: brown;
}
h1 {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/UyhKl8ZpZ9Pyaacl39ay?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You're close:

Setter:

```
$(".element").css("varname", "value");
```

Getter:

```
$(".element").css("varname");
```

For examples:

```
$(".element").css("display", "none");
```

Would set the display value to none.

```
$(".element").css("display");
```

Would return "none" as the current value of the css property.

**Edit for the literal CSS variable Comment:**

```
$(".div").css("background-color", "var(--main-color2)");
```

Will change the variable of an existing element, so assuming the variables exist you can swap styles around in this manner.

```
$(".div").css("background-color");
```

Unfortunately this returned `"rgb(255, 0, 0)"` for me. It grabbed the RGB that the variable represents. This was tested in Chrome, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: `display` isn't a CSS variable, it's a style name.

Comment: Not quite what I'm after, I am using the variable in a `transform`, so using `.css` returns a `matrix3d()` string. I plan to use the value of the variable in a calculation, so I need the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an invalid css name. Try using `.style` attr().

```
$(".element").attr("style","--varname:1"); // set the value
$(".element").attr("style"); // get the value
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/e6jqa3pn/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cssVar (on npm : jq-cssvar)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jq-cssvar), it's a jQuery plugin that gets the job done when it comes to css variables.

(Here is also a link to the [github repo](https://github.com/Voltra/jQueryCSSvar)).

Answer (score 0):

I've created monkey patch for jQuery css method so with it you can use just:

```
$(".element").css("--varname", 1);
```

the patched method call `getPropertyValue` or `setProperty` when variable start with two dashes or original method if not (it also handle object as first argument).

https://gist.github.com/jcubic/9ef9fa2561de8430e953e2fe62011c20

I'm providing link since the code may change in gist, if there is bug in it, but I think it's ok since it's pretty simple.